# How to get a specific node using the value of a node on its level on xsl

Tags: xslt

I have this kind of structure wherein I need to get the value of `<Sibling>` using the value of `<Child>` while the node is still on the `<GrandParent>`. I already tried putting a condition like this `Parent/Child[text()='171']`.

```
<GrandParent>
<Parent>
 <Child>172</Child>
 <Sibling>172_sibling</Sibling>
 <Child1>172</Child1>
 <Sibling1>172_sibling</Sibling1>
<Parent>
<Parent>
 <Child>171</Child>
 <Sibling>171_sibling</Sibling>
 <Child1>171</Child1>
 <Sibling1>171_sibling</Sibling1>
<Parent>
<Parent>
 <Child>173</Child>
 <Sibling>173_sibling</Sibling>
 <Child1>173</Child1>
 <Sibling1>173_sibling</Sibling1>
<Parent>
</GrandParent>
```

Comment: use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box on selected text to format as code/data/xml. good luck.

Comment: Remove all the "enter code here" annotations, hilight the code block and click the `{}` button.

Comment: Thanks guys that's a very useable advice for a newbie here like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get the value of `<Sibling>` using the value of `<Child>` while
>   the node is still on the `<GrandParent>`

From the context of `GrandParent`, the following instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Parent[Child=171]/Sibling"/>
```

will return `"171_sibling"`.

There is an implied assumption here that there is only one `Parent` node that satisfies the condition, and it has only one `Sibling` child node. At least in XSLT 1.0, the `xsl:value-of` instruction returns only the value of first node in the selected set.